# Get keyboard language or detect user input language in Android

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

### Problem Description

I'm trying to detect current selected language of the keyboard. For that purpose I use following code:

#### Code

```
/* Return the handle to a system-level service by name. The class of the returned
 * object varies by the requested name. */
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
/* Returns the current input method subtype. This subtype is one of the subtypes in the
 * current input method. This method returns null when the current input method doesn't
 * have any input method subtype. */
 InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
/* The locale of the subtype. This method returns the "locale" string parameter passed
 * to the constructor. */
 String locale = ims.getLocale();
```

but application throes `NoSuchMethodError` exception on `getCurrentInputMethodSubtype` function.

#### Question

Is there any way to get Keyboard selected language? If no how I can detect the language in which user typing in the application?

Comment: What's the `minSDK` in the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: @g00dy `minSDK` is 8 I know for this method I need 11 :(

Comment: Yes, you can access that, unless the `minSDK` is 11. To determine the language of the phone use `useLocale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`.

Comment: @g00dy I want to detect not the language of the phone, I want to know in which language user type, for example if he type in english I will show message if in Russian I will do some other action. This is what I want.

Comment: I'vo no idea how you can do that and if it's even possible. For the Roman languages - you have even common words. The russian language that you mentionned is cyrillic, but so is the Bulgarian too (they both have common word) - how can you distinguist between them?

Comment: @g00dy actually I use English, Russian and Armenian in my app, so I must think how I can do that :)

Comment: then why not let the user choose that before typing. A Stting maybe, which states - which language to you prefer ընկեր. And then, based on that do your thing after the user types the text in the box :)

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I did to get the available input languages:

```
private void printInputLanguages() {
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   List<InputMethodInfo> ims = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

   for (InputMethodInfo method : ims) {
       List<InputMethodSubtype> submethods = imm.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(method, true);
       for (InputMethodSubtype submethod : submethods) {
          if (submethod.getMode().equals("keyboard")) {
             String currentLocale = submethod.getLocale();
             Log.i(TAG, "Available input method locale: " + currentLocale);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList requires API 11

Comment: Returns empty string at `submethod.getLocale();` in Android P. Also `getLocale();` is deprecated from API level 24 onwards

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can get keyboard language by first detecting the locale of device keyboard and then getting the `Locale` object from it. For example,

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
    String localeString = ims.getLocale();
    Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
    String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

Here, `currentLanguage` will give your keyboard language. Hope this helps.

Comment: But be aware that it can return "zz" locale for example if QWERTY keyboard selected.

Comment: `ims.getLocale()` return empty string. Also it is deprecated from API 24 onwards

Comment: `getLocale()` is only deprecated because there's a newer, better `getLanguageTag()`. so android developers still believe in this functionality. the fact remains tho that not all keyboards will give you this information.

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 3):

**1st Method**

To get the selected language of your device. This might help u

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()        ---> en     
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()    ---> eng
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()         ---> US
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()     ---> USA
Locale.getDefault().toString()           ---> en_US
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() ---> English
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()  ---> United States
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()     ---> English (United States)
```

**2nd Method**

You can **extract** the language from the current locale. You can extract the locale via the standard Java API, or by using the Android Context. For instance, the two lines below are equivalent:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
String locale = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

No.  There's a phone locale, but the keyboard may ignore it by design (many keyboards allow you to switch languages just within the keyboard for bilingual users).  There's no API for the keyboard to report it has done so to the OS.

Comment: so there is no way to do that?

Comment: Nope.  The OS doesn't have the concept of a keyboard language.  Its done completely by the keyboards, and there's no way to query them.  You might find a keyboard that does it, but its not a common feature.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to get the selected language of your device. This might help u

`Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`

You might also do:

`Locale.getDefault().toString()` which gives a string that fully identifies the locale, e.g. "en_US".

Comment: I think I mentioned that I want to get keyboard selected language not a language of the device.

Comment: sorry my bad, there is a way for >=11 but your minSDK is 8... hmm

Comment: How to get the keyboard language?

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?