# How can I find the keyboard language the user is using?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

How can I find out in which language the users using the personal keyboards published by the Play Store developers are using the keyboard?

[Get keyboard language or detect user input language in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670922/get-keyboard-language-or-detect-user-input-language-in-android)

I tried the method in the first solution here but it gives me the phone's own system keyboard language. But what I want is to get the language in the custom keyboards the user is using. I'd be very grateful if anyone could help with this issue. Thank you from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The idea of a keyboard language isn't an Android concept.  It's something the keyboard app (a keyboard is an app and each manufacturer bundles their own-  there is no Android keyboard) creates on their own.  So there's no way for the OS to know about it, as that isn't even a concept to them. The only thing you can do is get the locale the phone is set to, but the keyboard doesn't need to be following that locale.